# How come Facebook's logotype is blue?

Tags: color, logo, color-theory

**Why is Facebook's logotype blue?**

---

Was there any special reasons for blue being choosen as the color of Facebook? What's the history behind it?

Comment: The frequency of light that reflects from the Facebook logo is of shorter wavelength than green, but longer than violet.

Comment: @q23.us except that color is not wavelength. Its something that happens in your brain. No magenta exists in wavelengths.

Comment: Fair enough, but if the wavelength changed, the blue might very well not happen in PetaspeedBeaver's brain. Then again, perhaps it's blue because Mary dropped some LSD. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia#Knowledge_argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook has [always been blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lM5v.jpg), and the guy who did the original designs [wasn't even a designer](http://mashable.com/2015/02/04/andrew-mccollum-facebook/), so any deep color theory or marketing meaning you put on it is probably just fluff.

According to the New Yorker, it's because Mark Zuckerberg is color blind...

> http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/09/20/the-face-of-facebook
>
> Colors don’t matter much to Zuckerberg; a few years ago, he took an online test and realized that he was red-green color-blind. Blue is Facebook’s dominant color, because, as he said, “blue is the richest color for me—I can see all of blue.”

When the logo was redesigned in 2005 by [Cuban Council](http://www.cubancouncil.com/), they continued to use the same blue as in the original design:

> http://www.downwithdesign.com/interviews/history-facebook-logo/
>
> **Was there any particular reason for the choice of blue as the main brand colour? If so, were any other colours originally selected?**
>
> We experimented with a variety of colors, but Mark was pretty adamant about using a blue that was derived from the original blue he had used on thefacebook.com, which he had chosen based on his colour blindness, so he told us.